# I want to Change Div Order with jquery or javascript through class name

Tags: jquery, html

my product is listing like that

```
<div class="post-744"></div>
<div class="post-740"></div>
<div class="post-751"></div>
<div class="post-746"></div>
<div class="post-748"></div>
```

i want them to list like that

```
<div class="post-740"></div>
<div class="post-744"></div>
<div class="post-748"></div>
<div class="post-746"></div>
<div class="post-751"></div>
```

i tried this but isnt working

```
jQuery('.post-740').insertAfter('.post-744').insertAfter('.post-748').insertAfter('.post-746').insertAfter('.post-751');
```

Comment: You sure you want 748 before 746?

Comment: How do you create those `div`? It will be better to order them before adding them to the dom.

Comment: yes i wnt 748 before 746 @caramba

Comment: its created dynamically by wordpress @aloisdgmovingtocodidact.com

Comment: Not sure how it is a dupe.....  @RoryMcCrossan order is not numeric order

Comment: Sorry @RoryMcCrossan I didnt Get you!! please explain how?

Comment: Problem here is you assume `insertAfter` changes reference when it does not. You would need to insert them from the end to beginning.

Comment: @epascarello my bad, jumped the gun and assumed the mis-ordering in the question was a typo. I've re-opened the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right track use `after()` instead of `insertAfter()`.

```js
jQuery('.post-740')
  .after($('.post-751'))
  .after($('.post-746'))
  .after($('.post-748'))
  .after($('.post-744'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="post-744">744 - 2</div>
<div class="post-740">740 - 1</div>
<div class="post-751">751 - 5</div>
<div class="post-746">746 - 4</div>
<div class="post-748">748 - 3</div>
```

Using an array

```js
var posts = ['.post-740', '.post-744','.post-748','.post-746','.post-751']

var topPost = jQuery(posts.shift())
while(posts.length) {
  topPost.after($(posts.pop()))
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="post-744">744 - 2</div>
<div class="post-740">740 - 1</div>
<div class="post-751">751 - 5</div>
<div class="post-746">746 - 4</div>
<div class="post-748">748 - 3</div>
```